# Common Lisp, reference to value and actual value

Tags: macros, reference, common-lisp

Consider this piece of code:

```
(defvar lst '(1 1))

(defmacro get-x (x lst)
  `(nth ,x ,lst))

(defun get-y (y lst)
  (nth y lst))
```

Now let us assume that I want to change the value of the elements of the list called *lst*, the *car* with *get-x* and the *cdr* with *get-y*.
As I try to change the value with *get-x* (with *setf*) everything goes fine but if I try it with *get-y* it signals an error (shortened):

; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: (SETF GET-STUFF)

Why does this happen?

I myself suspect that this happens because the macro simply expands and the function *nth* simply returns a reference to the value of an element in the list and the function on the other hand evaluates the function-call to *nth* and returns the value of the referenced value (sounds confusing).

Am I correct in my suspicions? 
If I am correct then how will one know what is simply a reference to a value and an actual value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error does not happen with the macro version, because, as you assumed, the expression `(setf (get-x some-x some-list) some-value)` will be expanded (at compile-time) into something like `(setf (nth some-x some-list) some-value)` (not really, but [the details of `setf`-expansion](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_a.htm) are complex), and the compiler knows, how to deal with that (i.e., there is a suitable `setf` expander defined for function `nth`).

However, in the case of `get-y`, the compiler has no `setf` expander, unless you provide one. The easiest way to do so would be

```
(defun (setf get-y) (new-value x ls)    ; Note the function's name: setf get-y 
    (setf (nth x ls) new-value))
```

Note, that there are a few conventions regarding `setf`-expanders:

1. The new value is always provided as the first argument to the `setf` function
2. All `setf` functions are supposed to return the new value as their result (as this is, what the entire `setf` form is supposed to return)

There is, BTW, no such concept as a "reference" in Common Lisp (at least not in the C++ sense), though there once were Lisp dialects which had *locatives*. Generalized place forms (ie., `setf` and its machinery) work very differently from plain C++ style references. See the CLHS, if you are curious about the details.

Comment: I actually did not believe that there were references in Common Lisp in the C++ sense until now, thanks for clearing that up. I had to figure out an explanation for my problem so that was what I came up with.

This whole thing with defining a function with a name like SETF GET-Y is kind of new to me as a concept... Anyway, I'll be doing some more research about this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

SETF is a macro.

The idea is that to set and read elements from data structures are two operations, but usually require two different names (or maybe even something more complex). SETF now enables you to use just one name for both:

```
(get-something x)
```

Above reads a datastructure. The inverse then simply is:

```
(setf (get-something x) :foobar)
```

Above sets the datastructure at X with :FOOBAR.

SETF does not treat (get-something x) as a reference or something like that. It just has a database of inverse operations for each operation. If you use GET-SOMETHING, it knows what the inverse operation is.

How does SETF know it? Simple:  you have to tell it.

For The NTH operation, SETF knows how to set the nth element. That's builtin into Common Lisp.

For your own GET-Y operation SETF does not have that information. You have to tell it. See the Common Lisp HyperSpec for examples. One example is to use DEFUN and (SETF GET-Y) as a function name.

Also note following style problems with your example:

- lst is not a good name for a DEFVAR variable. Use *list* as a name to make clear that it is a special variable declared by DEFVAR (or similar).
- '(1 2) is a literal constant. If you write a Common Lisp program, the effects of changing it are undefined. If you want to change a list later, you should cons it with LIST or something like COPY-LIST.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I indeed should use asterisks around global variables and so on, I was just very lazy and wanted to write what I wanted in the shortest way possible, my "real" code doesn't look like that. Thank you for your explanation!